# Euclids Division Algorithm problem.

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $a$ and $b$ are positive integers, then there are unique integers $q,r$ and $e = \pm 1$ such that$ a = bq + er $, where $-b/2 < r \leq b/2$.

I am always having trouble with these. :(

Using the division algorithm, we have $a = bq + r$ where $0 < r \leq b$ right?

$a = (2b)q + - bq + r$

i think this is wrong direction to go in.

Comment: No, the division algorithm gives $a = bq+r$ where $0 \leq r < b$.  $r$ ("the remainder") is whatever is left over after we have "subtracted as many copies of $b$ as we can from $a$" and is necessarily in $[0,b-1]$.

Comment: Where does $ \pm e$ come in to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b=1$ the result is obvious. So let $b\gt 1$.

The usual division algorithm says there exist integers $q'$ and $r'$ such that $a=bq'+r'$ where $0\le r'\lt b-1$.

If $r'\le b/2$ we are finished, for we can let $q=q'$ and $r=r'$.

If $r'\gt b/2$, let $q=q'+1$ and $r=r'-b$. Then $a=bq'+r'=b(q'+1)+r'-b=bq+r$, and $-b/2\lt r\lt 0$.

Comment: Thank you, what is the $\pm e $ all about in the question?

Comment: It is a worse way of putting it. The answer above says that we can get the "remainder" to be between $-b/2$ and $b/2$. The $e$ version really should have said $a=bq+er$ where $0\le r\le b/2$.

Comment: How is it the last line is true ? That because bq+r means -b/2<r<0

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: Sorry, still recovering, will not be able to respond for a few days.